# É possível usar com o Android Studio o SDK e o NDK?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk, android-ndk

Boa Noite!
Tenho um aplicativo que fiz usando o sdk.
Porém surgiu a necessidade de usar o NDK para poder usar algumas funções prontas já existentes em C/C++.
Como funciona nesse caso?
Eu preciso de refazer o projeto  para poder usar o NDK ou eu consigo continuar usando o SDK e só usar o NDK para fazer uso dessas funções em C/C++.
Li alguns tutoriais mas não consegui esclarecer minha dúvida.

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html?hl=pt-br

Comment: @IAMLuc eu já li isso e inclusive estou instalando por esse tutorial. Mas estou com medo de bugar meu app.
Não entendi se na hora de dar o build ele usa o NDK ou o SDK.